# Ubuntu 20.04 no longer compiles Tk8.6.10 easily?

Tags: compiling

since upgrading to Ubuntu_20.04 I notice that Tk8.6.10 no longer compiles easily.  The error I get is..

```
/home/jrh/Tktools/tk8.6.10/unix/../generic/tk.h:96:13: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
   96 | #   include <X11/Xlib.h>
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run

```
sudo apt install libx11-dev
```

and this should be resolved.

The package can be found by using [search for contents on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=X11%2FXlib.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&arch=any).

The installed package for known file can be found by

```
dpkg -S Xlib.h
```

Comment: This answer was truly appreciated and completely resolved the problem.  It saved me a lot of time !!!  This was my first question on AskUbuntu.  I was amazed at the response time.  Again, thank you.... Pilot6, much appreciated.

Comment: @Pilot6 adding link to [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=X11%2FXlib.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&arch=any) would be really useful to answer possible "why and how?" questions.

Comment: @N0rbert We don't need a link I guess. I can add some hint.